# Unscoped enum redefinition inside and outside the class

Tags: c++, class, enums

There is the example from 3.3.7/5:

```
typedef int c;
enum { i = 1 };
class X 
{
    char v[i]; // error: i refers to ::i
               // but when reevaluated is X::i
    int f() { return sizeof(c); } // OK: X::c
    char c;
    enum { i = 2 };
};
```

But it doesn't even compile. The following error is caused:

> test.cpp:9:12: error: declaration of ‘i’ [-fpermissive]
>
> test.cpp:4:8: error: changes meaning of ‘i’ from ‘ i’ [-fpermissive]

What is the sense of that example?

Comment: What is the document whose chapter/section you are referring to?

Comment: The example is demonstrating one of the rules stated above.

Comment: Examples that include comments: `// error:` represent code that does not compile. Whenever an example in the standard contains that comment the expected behavior is that *it doesn't even compile*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example demonstrates the class scope and its rules particularly the following rule

> 2) A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in
>   its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

In this example name i does not refer to the same name in the class scope. At first it refers to the global enumerator i and then it is reevaluated and refers to the class enumerator i.

So the compiler issues an error though as there is written in the rule it is implementation defined whether there will be a compiler diagnostic.

As for using name c in operator sizeof in function f then it is refers to the class data member with the same name because according to the rules

> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only
>   of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration,
>   but also of **all function bodies**

Comment: Can you explain the last quote in dumbed down terms and how it is different from the first rule?

Comment: What does re-evaluated in the completed scope mean? What does completed scope mean?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: The quote means that lookup is performed with only the declarations that happen *before* the place where lookup is triggered, **but** if lookup was to be done right before the closing brace in the class, it must refer to the same entity. The first part means that the compiler does not need to parse the whole class definition before figuring out what a declaration means (in the spirit of C and C++ most operations are performed using only the previous code), but it also requires from the user that the meaning of the declaration would not change if moved around inside the class.

Comment: @mindandsky The last quote means that there is no conflict between the global name c and the class data member x inside function f even though the function is defined before the class data member because the compiler will search the name at first in the class scope. So there is no re-evaluation of name c as a name of some other entity.